# Not able to add preview image in custom site Design

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-design, site-script

I am trying to create custom site design using PnP provisioning on my tenant. Everything works fine except preview Image. It is not coming in the site while I go to apply the design. If I list the available site designs using `Get-SPOSiteDesign` the the preview image url shows up as I provided in input but the image never comes up. I have tried the image from multiple location like from local system, SharePoint site library and even from the tenant level.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ThumbnailUrl` switch on the `Set-SPOSiteDesign` cmdlet:

```
Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity <GUID> -ThumbnailUrl <full URL to image> -PreviewImageAltText "Some Alt Text" -Title "This goes under the thumbnail"
```

I uploaded the preview image to an `Organisational` Media library which everyone has read access so the image appears now when selecting "From your organization" under "Apply a site template".

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen site design accepts preview image URL from any site.

Try below trick it should for you.

1. Set PreviewImageUrl as empty so it should apply default image. use below script

   Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity  -PreviewImageUrl ""
2. Once you see the default Preview image then using the same PowerShell command set the correct URL.

   Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity  -PreviewImageUrl "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/DocumentLib/333.png"

Comment: Hey Sajid, I have tried this but the result is same. The thing is even if I am providing the preview image url while creating the site design, it shows the default image only.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue and found this site with solution: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1197

Please use `-ThumbnailUrl` instead of `-PreviewImageUrl`.